# INDK - Livin with even LES; what does LES stand for

Tags: song-title, punk

What does LES refer to?

[INDK - Livin' with even LES](https://youtu.be/pjmGuXd8RZA)

Comment: maybe a play on words, LES for less ? but other meanings possible too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The band is from New York and more precisely from the [**Lower East Side**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_East_Side) of Manhattan.

This song says:

> Today - the **Lower East Side** is yuppified with fat cats and their poor folk hide

It's also a pun, like Angst suggested with the word *less*. So it does have a double meaning because the LES of Manhattan is a poor neighbourhood.